# Firebase Leaderboard Sorting

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a leaderboard with firebase, but I want it to sort based on points, for example

1. 200 points
2. 50  points
3. 30 points

How would I do that?

**This is my code:**

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userRef = database.ref('countries');
userRef.orderByChild("points").once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var tr;
    var rank = 1;

    snapshot.forEach((countrySnapshot) => {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + rank + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + countrySnapshot.val().country.toLocaleString() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + countrySnapshot.val().points.toLocaleString() + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
        rank = rank + 1;
});
})
```

**This is how it looks like right now:**

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oxJ8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the array before doing `forEach`. Looking at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#orderbychild)

> Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order. If
> multiple children have the same numerical value for the specified
> child node, they are sorted by key.

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userRef = database.ref('countries');
userRef.orderByChild("points").once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var tr;
    var rank = 1;
    snapshot.reverse(); //add in this line
    snapshot.forEach((countrySnapshot) => {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + rank + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + countrySnapshot.val().country.toLocaleString() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + countrySnapshot.val().points.toLocaleString() + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
        rank = rank + 1;
});
})
```

Comment: I get this error when I use that code "Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.reverse is not a function"

Comment: Can you get the typeof snapshot? console.log(typeof snapshot);

Comment: It returned "object"